# Choosing a proxy caching approach to work with Google Calendar API

Tags: algorithm, caching, google-calendar-api

I need a suitable caching approach for use with an enterprise portal showing data from the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/).  What algorithms or design patterns are best applicable?

The Google Calendar API is limited by number of requests per day (*defaults to 10,000 requests/day*  - I have requested more) and rate of access (*5 requests/second/user*).

There are two core API methods that I expect to use, one to get a [list of user calendars](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) (*1 API hit*) and one to [download the events of an individual calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) (*1 API hit per calendar*).

Both the calendar list and individual calendars contain **etag** values which can be used to help avoid unnecessary API requests.   If you have a list of individual calendar **etag** values then you can see if any of these have changed by just querying the calendar list. (Unfortunately a HTTP *304 Not Modified* response is still counted as an API hit).

Also I don’t really want to download and cache the entire calendar contents (so maybe just a few days or weeks at a time).

I need to find an approach which tries to minimize the number of API calls but doesn't try to store everything.  It also needs to be able to cope with occasionally fetching data from unchanged calendars because the "time sliding window" on the calendar data has moved on.  I would like the system to be backed by data storage so that multiple portal instances could share the same data.